# Adding value to List<String> = new ArrayList<String>();

Tags: java, android, list

Sorry i really dont know how to do this, last resort but to ask.
I wanted to add values to the string list. But my code is not working

```
private List<String> sample = new ArrayList<String>(){"item1","item2","item3"};
```

Comment: Agreed, there are at least 10 different examples of doing exactly what he's asking there.

Comment: I do not see this as duplicate. Nobody seem to notice that question specifies `private List<String>` and answers stipulate `ArrayList<String>` which is another thing. So this is not actually even answered properly. But fulfilled the cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("item1");
    add("item2");
    add("item3");
}}
```

OR

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("item1");
list.add("item2");
list.add("item3");
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution sir, may i ask why is there double quotes,{{}}.

Comment: @lonelearner In the first case we are making an anonymous inner class with an instance initializer (double brace initialization) For More : http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization

Answer (score 5):

Here it is:

```
List<String> sample = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3"));
```

Comment: Thank you, both of your answer work, i tried very hard to look for a solution on android developer, but i do not know which page to look for.

Comment: Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is serializable and implements RandomAccess.
This method also provides a convenient way to create a fixed-size list initialized to contain several elements:

     List<String> stooges = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html